Is there any global settings to add \limits to evey \sum?
Is there any global settings to add \limits to evey \sum, \bigcup etc?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\ImposeLimitsOnOperator[1]{%

  \expandafter\let\csname original#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname%

  \expandafter\edef\csname #1\endcsname{\csname original#1\endcsname\limits}%

}

\newcommand\WithLimits{\forcsvlist{\ImposeLimitsOnOperator}}

\WithLimits{lim,sum,bigcup,inf,prod}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document} 

\def\xtest{
\sum_{i=0}^{3} \int_{-5}^{5} \lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{j=0}^{n}
}

\( \xtest \)

\[ \xtest \]

\end{document}

unicode-math  lose effectiveness why?

LaTeX's Unicode-math re-defines these operators at \begin{document}.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Another "feature" of the unicode-math package is that it overrides the nosumlimits and nonamelimits options of the amsmath/mathtools packages.

what do you mean that unicode-math 'loses effectiveness'?

as wipet says you would need to delay the redefinition until after begin document, but doing this destroys inline math, the whole point of which is to adjust the math setting to stay within baseline spacing.

@Mico that's probably easily fixed (you could open an issue on the unicode-math github?)

@DavidCarlisle - I've gone ahead and opened an issue on unicode-math github. I may have misspoken earlier: Only 'nosumlimits', but not 'nonamelimits', is affected.

yes thanks, I got an email:-) @Mico

@DavidCarlisle - You're welcome. :-) I just noticed that the intlimits option of the amsmath package is also disabled if unicode-math is loaded. I've opened an additional new issue on GitHub.

Everybody is entitled their tastes… I'd never use \limits unless in a few selected places.
If you really want to spoil your document, here's the recipe:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand\ImposeLimitsOnOperator[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname original#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\edef\csname #1\endcsname{\csname original#1\endcsname\limits}%
}

\newcommand\WithLimits{\forcsvlist{\ImposeLimitsOnOperator}}

\AtBeginDocument{\WithLimits{lim,sum,bigcup,inf,prod}}

\begin{document}

\def\xtest{%
  \sum_{i=0}^{3} \int_{-5}^{5} \lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{j=0}^{n}
}

\( \xtest \)

\[ \xtest \]

\end{document}


I removed the spurious blank lines;

most importantly, I delayed the setting at begin document.



With better code, which doesn't fix the very disputable output you get…
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\WithLimits}{m}
 {
  \AtBeginDocument { \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} { \dontdothis_impose:cc {original##1} {##1} } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \dontdothis_impose:NN
 {
  \NewCommandCopy{#1}{#2}
  \RenewDocumentCommand{#2}{}{#1\limits}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \dontdothis_impose:NN {cc}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\WithLimits{lim,sum,bigcup,inf,prod}

\begin{document}

\def\xtest{\sum_{i=0}^{3} \int_{-5}^{5} \lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{j=0}^{n}}

\( \xtest \)

\[ \xtest \]

\end{document}

